# Reference same model twice with different foreign keys or create a many-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, many-to-many, single-table-inheritance

I have an app in Rails where I've create a model called User and another called Task.

The model User has an `enum` for roles, which means that I can have an User that is a client or a developer:

```rb
require 'bcrypt'

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks

  enum :role => [
    :client, 
    :developer
  ]

  has_secure_password

  validates_uniqueness_of :document, :email
  validates_presence_of :birthdate, 
                        :credits,
                        :document, 
                        :email, 
                        :name, 
                        :neighborhood, 
                        :phone, 
                        :street, 
                        :street_number, 
                        :zipcode
end
```

The model Task can be managed by an client or by a developer:

```rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  enum :priority => [
    :low,
    :medium,
    :high
  ]
  validates_presence_of :description, :title
end
```

I'm pretty sure that it would be better if I split the table User in two other tables, called Client and Developer, for example, but their attributes are the same and in the future, I want to be able to quickly change the User with the role `:client` to the role `:developer`, without having to create a record in the table Developer and destroying the other in the table Client.

My question is: thinking in good practices, is it better to insert two fields in the model Task, one called `client_id` and the other called `developer_id` and use the [Single-table inheritance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance) or to creating a [many-to-many relationship](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) between the model Task and the model User, and just check the role of each user that is being reference in the Task?

Comment: ` I want to be able to quickly change the User with the role :client to the role :developer, without having to create a record in the table Developer and destroying the other in the table Client.` Can you explain ?

Comment: Common way to handle your case (if I understood all conditions correctly) is: Rolify gem for role management and Pundit/Cancancan for authorisation